# Searching a smartcard that's crossplatform

Tags: certificate, smartcard

I'm searching a smart card for storing (PKI) certificates. The certificates on the smart card need to be retrieved on Windows (supporting Active Directory login), Linux, and Mac OS X.

I found some like the Feitian PKI smart card but from what understand it's not supported on Mac OS X.

Are there any smart cards out there that have drivers on all three the platforms?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the [OpenPGP smart card](http://shop.kernelconcepts.de/product_info.php?products_id=141&osCsid=3278a059fbfa5937fbfac8efa89dde1d); since it's OpenPGP compliant, and that works on all three platforms, I have to conclude that the card does, too.

Whether you can find a smart card reader that works on everything is a different question.  I have an SCM Microsystems SCR335 that works very nicely with my FSFE Fellowship smart card (which is itself an OpenPGP smart card) under Linux; I'd be quite surprised if that didn't work under MacOS and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify which specific PKI implementation & email encryption type, for example, x509 SMIME vice PGP/Openpgp as I am currently unaware of a card stock that supports both PGP/Openpgp and x509 SMIME implementations (no one really uses PGP with x509 certs)

I know the Gemalto TOP DL GX4 144k cardstock used with the Department of Defense's Common Access Card (CAC) is compatible with Windows, Linux, OS X, iOS, Blackberry, and many other operating systems, and has a ton of compatible readers and multiple middleware solutions.

Reference:

http://www.gemalto.com/public_sector/omb1111/index.html